# how to prevent EF from trying to map a method on my model?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

So, I've got a "Speaker" class, with normal properties, and a plain old method like this:

```
public string FullNameFirstLast()
{
    return FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework Code First Magic Unicorn edition, and I get this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to
>   Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String FullNameFirstLast()'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Which seems odd, since it is a method and not a property, so I wonder why EF would care about it anyway...  So I tried telling EF to ignore it like so:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Speaker>()
        .Ignore(ignore => ignore.FullNameFirstLast())
        ;
```

Which doesn't help, because now I get this error message instead:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   expression 'ignore =>
>   ignore.FullNameFirstLast()' is not a
>   valid property expression. The
>   expression should represent a
>   property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty' 
>   VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.

How do I do this?  I'm assuming that I can have methods on my model objects with EF, right??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a problem of mapping. It is problem of using the method in Linq-to-entities query. You can't use custom methods or custom properties in Linq-to-entities query because EF provider doesn't know how to translate them to SQL.

Comment: yep.  thanks!  I wasn't querying it directly, but I had a use where I had _repo.Speakers().OrderBy(...) using that method.  apparently EF tries to pass along the order by to SQL and so had this problem.  I needed to first materialize the data from the DB, THEN sort it.  thanks!